# Pass value to function, constructor, shader: "pass", "give", "transfer" or other

Tags: differences, programming

Which word is better to use to indicate the transfer of a value to a function, the constructor of a class, or to transfer data from an vertex shader to a fragment shader? I tend to the word "pass". But is it always right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Pass" is the normal term, though I think maybe I've heard "give" occasionally in informal situations. The word "transfer" is normally used when transferring data between systems, not between functions within a single program.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks You for the comment! I am also inclined to this opinion.